# How can I set a state to 'null' on click in a MERN w/ Redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

I want to call an action in React on a click. I would like the action to set an object in the store to `null`.

Here is my component where the clicking will occur. I want the state to be null when the user clicks to leave the page.
This was my attempt. During which I learned you cannot import and call an action `nullPhoto`. If I import `nullPhoto` with `connect` the object is `null` all the time.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Navbar,
  NavItem,
  Container
} from 'reactstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Headroom from 'react-headroom'
import Logout from '../auth/Logout'
import { nullPhoto } from '../actions/photoActions';

class AppNavbar extends Component {

  clearPhoto() {
    this.nullPhoto()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Headroom>
        <Navbar >
          <Container>
            <Link to={'/'} >
              <h4 className="home-text" onClick={this.clearPhoto} >Home</h4>
            </Link>
            <NavItem>
              <Logout/>
            </NavItem>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>
        </Headroom>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  array: state.photos.array,
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(AppNavbar);
```

My action needs work too.
I don't know how to make it just set the object to `null` without all the axios stuff. How do I dispatch the object to null all by itself without a .then attached to something?

```
export const nullPhoto = file => (dispatch) => {
  axios
  .get('/api/items')
  .then(res =>
    dispatch({
      type: NULL_PHOTO,
    })
  )
}
```

The reducer is the only thing I don't think there is a problem with.

```
case NULL_PHOTO:
    return {
    ...state,
    array: null
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your action to the following, to remove the `axios` call.

```js
export const nullPhoto = () => ({ type: NULL_PHOTO});
```

Also map dispatch to your components `props` with the second argument of `connect`.

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  nullPhoto: () => dispatch(nullPhoto()),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps // <-- Here
)(AppNavbar);
```

Then call the dispatch action which is mapped to your components `props` in the `clearPhoto` method of your component.

```js
// (...)

clearPhoto = () => {
  this.props.nullPhoto()
}

// (...)
```

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` when I click the element with the  `clearPhoto()` function, which calls `this.props.nullPhoto()`. I got the same error from Federico's answer (after I fixed it). It doesn't like calling that action for some reason. BTW it wasn't me downvoting any answers.

Comment: @Renoldus I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Comment: I appreciate you also answering the part about removing axios from the action, but I'm getting an error on that line `TypeError: dispatch is not a function`.

Comment: I actually should have had `export const nullPhoto = file => (dispatch) => {` to the nullPhoto action. I updated it in my question. Sorry, I having figured this => and () = stuff out yet.

Comment: Are you using `redux-thunk`? I've updated my answer and changed the action, can you try again?

Comment: I am. Thank you. This is a struggle to work out but I am learning lots with your help.

Comment: @Renoldus Thanks, happy to hear it worked out for you!

Comment: If you don't mind one more question... I thought `dispatch` was key to updating the store. Is it easy to explain to me what dispatch does?

Comment: @Renoldus The `dispatch` method, dispatches (sends) and action to your reducers. It triggers **all** reducers and the reducers then take care of updating the state. All your reducers run every time you dispatch an action with `dispatch`. However, only the ones which care about the action dispatched, change the store.

Comment: Thank you. . . .

Comment: @Renoldus I hope it helped! Do not hesitate to ask again, if it didn't help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your action in your `mapDispatchToProps`

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  array: state.photos.array,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setNullPhoto: () => dispatch(nullPhoto()),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AppNavbar);
```

Then, in your component, that action will be injected via props. So you'll need to modify your componet as follows:

```
class AppNavbar extends Component {

  clearPhoto() {
    this.props.setNullPhoto()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Headroom>
        <Navbar >
          <Container>
            <Link to={'/'} >
              <h4 className="home-text" onClick={this.clearPhoto} >Home</h4>
            </Link>
            <NavItem>
              <Logout/>
            </NavItem>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>
        </Headroom>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There are multiple errors in this answer. You used the wrong method name in the component, you forgot a semicolon in the `mapDispatchToProps` declaration and `setNullPhoto` is the result of dispatching instead of being a function to dispatch from when needed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I have to the green check to the other guy because he also helped me with the action. Thank you!